# Access ng serve from other server

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a web server which works on localhost:8080. It serves index.html. Also there's a node server running `ng serve` (localhost:4200).

I'd like web server to use angular server, so added manually entry .ts files to index.html, but HMR doesn't work because it's trying to access `http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node`. I tried to set `deployUrl` and `baseHref` in `.angular-cli.json`, but nothing changed. Is there anyway to do it or the whole setup is not good?

Comment: There is no need to use `ng serve` to host an angular application. You should build it using `ng build`, and host it with a web server such as nginx or apache. Serving index.html from the build directory should be all you need

Comment: @user184994 it's for development solely. To support live reload and serving files from memory

Answer (score 0):

index.html does not access .ts files. There is no point of putting references to them in any index.html. Typescript gets compiled to Javascript before being processed by any browser. This compilation is what both the commands `ng build` and `ng serve` do. `ng build` also does some optimizations first (minification without source-maps, aot etc) while `ng serve` compiles quickly but unoptimized and starts up a server and listens to code-changes. But that server (as the warning in the cli says) is not production-ready and very instable

For production you should not use `ng serve`. You should only compile using `ng build` and deploy the /dist/ folder on a production server like nginx or upload it to a service like firebase, heroku etc. with their respective clis.

Comment: Yeah, that's understood. Sorry, i meant not .ts files but compiled .js files. For now i'm trying to setup development server with HMR. The problem is that since index.html is served not by webpack server, it can't access HMR updates since it tries to access web server.

Comment: You want to have HMR on a remote server (if yes why?) or on localhost?

Comment: I want index.html to be served from web server (localhost:8080) and all Angular stuff to be served from angular dev server (localhost:4200). So it's remote in some way. I thought it would be easier to setup security this way.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run angular with `ng serve --public-host http://localhost:4200`. This way webpack knows where to pull updates from.